# Is WP Query skipping to check next post when an argument is not met?

Tags: wp-query

If a post fails to meet the first argument (publish), does wp query still do the meta comparison or is it skipping to check the next post immediately?

The question is NOT about the output, but rather how wp query works before the output. For an example if you have a database with thousands of posts and only five is published. My concern is the query is getting slow if it does the meta comparison on all posts.

Example code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
    'meta_key'     => 'expiredate',
    'meta_value'   => date( 'Ymd' ),
    'meta_compare' => '<'
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: `WP_Query` just generates an SQL query that's performed on the database, so any behaviour in that regards would be down to how MySQL works. WordPress itself does not perform the comparison.

Comment: this query will be slow but it'll be slow because you asked it to filter post IDs by their meta values, and that table is not designed for those kinds of queries, this is why dedicate tables were created for categories and tags instead of just storing them in post meta. Jacob is right too, WordPress doesn't do the comparisons, it asks the database in an SQL query. You would need to test this yourself by runningthe raw SQL through an EXPLAIN query to see how your specific database install plans the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does wp query still do the meta comparison

**WP Query doesn't do comparisons, it asks the database to do them in an SQL query. MySQL/MariaDB does the comparison.**

You would need to test this yourself by running the raw SQL through an `EXPLAIN` query to see how your specific database install plans the query. Different database versions and configurations may behave differently.

---

If your suspicion is correct, there will be very little that can be done about it from the WordPress side. But this is a red herring, a wild goose chase. This is not a problem you can fix and everything will be super fast, because this query will always be fundamentally slow.

Keep in mind that because it's the post meta table, and that table isn't designed for these kinds of queries to be performant, the number of posts requested per page is 10 by default, and it needs to figure out the number of pages, so a full table scan is unavoidable with the code in your question. Otherwise how would it know there are only 5?

This query will be slow but it'll be slow because you asked it to filter post IDs by their meta values, and that table is not designed for those kinds of queries, this is why dedicate tables were created for categories and tags instead of just storing them in post meta. `meta_query` and the associated `meta_value` parameters do not scale as it involves a full table scan. As your site grows in scale, the query will get progressively slower and more expensive. Having a numeric value for your post meta will help mitigate this, and there are far worse post meta queries you could have asked `WP_Query` to create.

Your ideal situation is likely one where posts have an `expired` tag of some kind that gets automatically added via a regular cron job, but that's another topic that requires another question.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. If I understand you right, it would be a better solution to tag expired posts and use that in the query instead of meta values. To tag those posts I would still use a meta query, but as that happens in a scheduled job it wont affect end-user? Or am I thinking wrong here?

Comment: no, if you use post meta to tag posts it would still be slow because finding posts by their post meta values is expensive and slow. It would be marginally faster. Think of it as the difference between driving from France to New Zealand vs cycling to New Zealand. If you want to filter/flag/tag/mark/group posts, use a taxonomy, not post meta. Note that you can still store an expiration date in post meta, it's how you query for those posts that's important. You don't want to check all post meta to see which ones have expired and which don't, you want unexpired posts. So flag the posts as expired

Comment: Also note that taxonomies don't have to be public, you can just as easily register a utility taxonomy to store intermediate data to speed up queries to implement features, e.g. a `post_flags` or an `internal_markers` taxonomy with `public` set to `false`. Your cron job can then do the expensive meta query and use it to add the cheap taxonomy term for the frontend query

Comment: Massive thanks for taking the time Tom. What you wrote in your comments was what I meant in my first comment if I am not totally out of bounds here. Maybe I am using the wrong terminology, what I meant by scheduled job was a cron job like this:

1. Cron job scheduled daily with the expensive meta query tagging expired posts  2. Then front-end query using that tag/taxonomy to select the output for end-user.

Hope I got you right this time :)